# AWS RDS PostgreSQL 10 Foreign Table between nodes and databases won't work

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, foreign-data-wrapper, postgresql-10

I have three RDS servers (created in AWS in March of 2018) running PostgreSQL 10.1. 
I need to create foreign tables between databases on each node, and also between databases on different nodes.
 Here's a sample of my sql to set this up

```
CREATE SERVER fserver FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'rds2', dbname 'db_on_rds_2', port '5432');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER fserver OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'secret');


 CREATE FOREIGN TABLE ftable
 (
    id character varying(100) 
)
SERVER fserver;
```

the error I get is this (from rds1) when executing:

```
select * from ftable limit 10;
```

is

```
 ERROR:  could not connect to server "rds2"
    DETAIL:  FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    SQL state: 08001
```

I get this error regardless if I am trying to query a foreign table that is on the same RDS, or on a different one.

I think it's a permission issue with the postgres user, but I tried granting everything, but no joy.

Anyone have any insight on what this might be? I've spent many hours on this.

rds1 and rds2 are not the real hostnames, I'm using the actual hostnames.

Comment: maybe firewall on AWS block connection?

Comment: it was actually an ecoding error with the generation of the SQL code from java